# How to reconnect when irc client times out (Ping timeout: 240 seconds)

Tags: c#, reconnect

I'm using `ircdotnet` library, and I'm trying to reconnect on a timeout, but when I timeout in IRC, the client doesn't recognize it's disconnected, what is wrong with my code, how can I reconnect when it's timedout?

```
namespace IRCBOT
{
    class Program
    {
        public IrcClient zIrcClient = new IrcClient();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connect();
        }
        public static void Connect()
        {

            Program p = new Program("irc.server.net", new IrcUserRegistrationInfo()
            {
                NickName = "justatest",
                UserName = "test",
                RealName = "test",
                Password = ""
            });
        }
        public Program(string host, IrcRegistrationInfo info)
        {
            try
            {
                zIrcClient.Connect(host, 6667, false, info);
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss ") + "Connecting");
                zIrcClient.Connected += ircClient_Connected;
                zIrcClient.Registered += ircClient_Registered;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (!zIrcClient.IsConnected)
                    {
                        zIrcClient.Disconnected += ircClient_Disconnected;
                    }
                    string text = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (text == "/quit")
                    {
                        zIrcClient.Quit();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        zIrcClient.LocalUser.SendMessage("#testchamber", text);
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
                zIrcClient.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        private void ircClient_Connected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss ") + "Connected");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { 
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        private void ircClient_Disconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss ") + "Disconnected");
                zIrcClient.Connected -= ircClient_Connected;
                zIrcClient.Registered -= ircClient_Registered;
                zIrcClient.Disconnected -= ircClient_Disconnected;
                zIrcClient.Dispose();
                Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
    private void ircClient_Registered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        zIrcClient.Channels.Join("#testchamber");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the Disconnected event is connected to your event handler at the time that it occurs?
Maybe instead of conditionally connecting your event handler,

```
if (!zIrcClient.IsConnected)
{
    zIrcClient.Disconnected += ircClient_Disconnected;
}
```

you could just connect it the same way as your other event handlers:

```
zIrcClient.Connected += ircClient_Connected;
zIrcClient.Registered += ircClient_Registered;
zIrcClient.Disconnected += ircClient_Disconnected;
```

Comment: No, it didn't work, it doesn't seem to know it's disconnected.

Comment: The `ircClient_Disconnected` event doesn't get called this way... Anyone else have a idea?

Comment: Is there some sort of ircClient_Timeout event that happens instead?

Comment: Can't check right now, I'm on Holiday but I will check it as zoon as I get back, but if I remember right there wasn't

Comment: There is no such event :( Here is the documentation: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/IrcDotNet

Comment: OK, the documentation doesn't mention timeouts, and it doesn't look like timeouts are handled by the library. Have you tried the ircClient.Error event? I think the SocketException resulting from a timeout should show up there...